# Troubles using astype in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert my dataset input matrix marked as X to the type float. I have some columns which has the thousands divided by '.' and the decimals too.

When I enter de command:

```
X=X.astype(float)
```

I get the error that tells me that it is impossible to convert string to float. I have try to include the thousands and decimal field when I import the dataset but I am not sure how to use it, could anyone help me?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bypass the errors in the column which is mixed type, I'm using the method in below.

```
x=pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain your solution.